# Want to add image in first two columns in ListView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listview

I am trying to add image for first two columns in ListView. But I could not add image for second column. My code is..

```
            foreach ( DataRow row in _dtCategories.Rows )
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem ( );
                for ( int i = 1 ; i < _dtCategories.Columns.Count ; i++ )
                {
                    item.ImageIndex = 0;
                    item.SubItems.Add ( " " );
                    item.ImageIndex = 1;                        
                    item.SubItems.Add ( row [ "Category" ].ToString ( ) );     
                }
                lvCategories.Items.Add ( item );
            }
```

So my output is..
[image]

But I want to add image in first two columns.

Help me..

Comment: It is my understanding that the .ImageIndex property can only be used once similar to the .Tag

Answer (score 0):

Try ItemTemplate:

```
  <!--ListView-->
        <ListView x:Name="lb_Users">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Grid Width="150">
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                     <!-- other columns-->
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <Image Source="mypic.png"/>
                 <Image Source="mypic2.png"/>
                 <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ....}" />
                     <!-- other columns-->
                 </Grid>
             </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Are you sure the OP is using WPF?

Comment: It was WPF propaganda (*joke*). Actually topic starter sayd nothing about visual technology  he works with.

Comment: =) yeah well, I was thinking that since the OP didn't state the technology, maybe you should have added a comment asking for that first and perhaps save you the "trouble" of adding a possible incorrect answer.